# Mock a class and then unmock it in jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, aws-cdk, ts-jest

I have a cdk project in typescript and I am trying to write unit tests for the first app.ts. So below is the sample code for it -

```
    import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
    export class MyApp extends cdk.App {
      constructor() {
        super();
        const sharedContext = this.node.tryGetContext('shared');
        const myProjectName = sharedContext['projectName'];
        // some more functionality
       //create stack
    }
    }
    
    const app = new MyApp();
    app.synth();
```

the problem is when in my test file i.e. app.test.ts i am importing like -

```
import { MyApp } from '../app';
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
describe('app', () => {
  let mockedcontext: jest.SpyInstance<any, unknown[]>;
  const expectedSharedcontext = {
    projectName: 'exampleSharedContext',
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockedcontext = jest
      .spyOn(cdk.ConstructNode.prototype as any, 'tryGetContext')
      .mockReturnValue(expectedSharedcontext);
    Object.defineProperty(MyApp.prototype, 'sharedContext', { value: expectedSharedcontext });
    new MyApp();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  test('constructor', () => {
    expect(mockedcontext).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

it is importing the creation of new object as well at the bottom and hence none of my mocks are working to test the app.ts. Any idea how do I just test the functionality of class MyApp.

Comment: How did you mock?

Comment: there is a node.trygetcontext inside the class which is fetching data. usually what i do is mock it using jest.spyon and then create new object of the class and then check that trygetcontext was being called. Since in the above scenario the new object is already there in the app.ts my mock is not working.

Comment: Please, provide relevant code for the question. You can mock methods on class `prototype` but it's unknown if it's the case because you didn't show it.

Comment: I have added more code now.

Comment: My experience is that you don't have unit testing CDK code. Instead, you write integration tests for your application. If there is any failed test, it's due to either your cdk-infra or an application bug.